# Show that a line l intersects all four sides of a quadrilateral given that none of the four points ABCD lies on l.

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a quadrilateral with a line l intersecting the segment AB. None of the four points ABCD lies on l.

I have to show that l either intersects two sides of ABCD or all four sides. I get how to show that it intersects two sides(using the Plane separation Postulate), but how do I do it for all four? (And is that even possible???)

Comment: A [quadrilateral with self-intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_quadrilateral), like [antiparallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallelogram)...?

Comment: @CiaPan I think even with self-intersection line $l$ would intersect either 2 or 4 sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose e.g. that $l$ intersects sides $AB,BC,CD.$ Then $A,B$ on opposite sides of $l,$ also $B,C$ on opposite sides, finally $C,D$ on opposite sides. This implies that $A,D$ are on opposite sides, so that side $AD$ intersects line $l.$

Here is a picture of how such an arrangement is possible:

[image: Quaddy]

Diagram courtesy of Peter Woolfitt.

Comment: Do you mind if I add a picture to your post? I thought it might be fun to make, and now I have it, but your post already fully answers the question. ([This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwOOb.png))

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt By all means insert the picture, if it can be done without using a link. If done, you can include something like "diagram courtesy of Peter Woolfitt."

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the awkwardness